# Cambiar el bg color y color a checkbox disabled

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy intentando cambiar los estilos a un checkbox que tiene en el html la propiedad "disabled", pero no se aplican los estilos.

```
.form-control:disabled, .form-control[readonly]{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:disabled {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

En mi html me aparece como que coge ese background, pero no lo tiene

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene el mismo color gris muy opaco..... ( he limpiado la cache, f5, ctr+ f5, ctr shift f5 y nada.. sigue del mismo color)

Lo curioso es que ese input "que es un checkbox"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sigue apareciendo de ese color a pesar de que en propiedades tiene bg color yellow..

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias !

Comment: Investigando un poco, he encontrado este [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css) a StackOverflow general donde mencionan cómo realizar tu problema con CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder dar el formato que tu quieras a una casilla de verificación necesitas crear una nueva casilla y esconder (display:none) la que viene de fabrica.

En el siguiente ejemplo la creao utilizando el pseudoelemento  after

```css
[type="checkbox"]{display:none;position:relative}

[type="checkbox"] + label:after{
   content:"";
   display:inline-block;
   width:1em;height:1em;
   outline:1px solid silver;  
}


[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label:after{
   background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">    
     <input type="checkbox" id="disabled" disabled="disabled" >
     <label for="disabled">checkbox:</label>
</form>
```

Por favor lea más acerca de [casillas de verificación con estilo](http://w3.unpocodetodo.info/css3/checkbox-estilo.php)